# How to return real price in strategy while using renko/average K

Tags: pine-script

I am using renko or average k in strategy, however, the backtest is using the renko-price/average K-price to return the result, how can I get a result with real price?

Comment: Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Designing strategies on Renko charts is not recommended, as Renko calcs on historical bars and the realtime bar differ, so you will not be able to reproduce your backtested strat in realtime. See [Backtesting on Non-Standard Charts: Caution! - PineCoders FAQ](https://www.tradingview.com/script/q9laJNG9-Backtesting-on-Non-Standard-Charts-Caution-PineCoders-FAQ/) and [Strategy produces unrealistic results on non-standard chart types (Heikin Ashi, Renko, etc.)](https://www.tradingview.com/?solution=43000481029).

You could work from a standard chart using Renko calcs derived from normal bars, with something like [this](https://www.tradingview.com/script/iZJLDybM-Renko-Chart/) as a starting point. This would allow you to run a Renko strategy on normal bars, so your orders can be executed at known time and price points.